# Why is OnClick not changing the colour back?

Tags: javascript, html, if-statement, onclick

So I'm testing something and I'm trying to make it so that when I click on this red button, it'll turn green, and when I click it again, it turns red again. Can someone help me out ? I'm very very new to this

```
<img id= "redBox1"  src="red.png" 
onClick="
if (redBox1 === true)
{redBox1 == false;
    src='green.png';}
else (redBox1 === false)
{redBox1 == true);
    src='red.png';}" />
```

aside from changing it back to red, I'm also trying to make it so that whenever the button turns green, redBox1 = false.

Thank you in advance for your help

Comment: You aren't storing `redBox1` anywhere... It's going to be easier if you use something like jQuery because then you don't need to write your onClick code in the element and make your HTML difficult to debug...

Comment: Just to be clear:
=== means exactly the same
== means the same after loose conversion
= means assignment

Answer (score 2):

`redBox1` is a DOM element (via the horrible "Given an element an ID, make a global JS variable" mechanism introduced in IE 4, not a Boolean. It doesn't make sense to compare it to `true` or `false`.

You should be examining the `src` property instead.

```
<img id="redBox1" src="red.png">
<script>
document.getElementById('redBox1').addEventListener('click', toggleImage);
function toggleImage(evt) {
    if (evt.target.src === "red.png") {
       evt.target.src = "green.png";
    } else {
       evt.target.src = "red.png";
    }
}
</script>
```